# How to copy selected applications one grid view to another gridview

Tags: android, gridview, custom-lists, installed-applications

could you please guide me, I am going correct way or not??
1.Getting installed applications in 1 st grid view.(Done)
2.select favorite apps from gridview 1 st grid view. (Here im getting array list[whats up,faceboot])(DONE)
3.May I know ,How to bind array list data to another custom grid view.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    ArrayList<AppList> mArrayProducts = clad.getCheckedItems();
                    String[] outputStrArr = new String[mArrayProducts.size()];
                    //values.add(outputStrArr);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected Items:"+mArrayProducts,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }  
Can u please help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> mArrayProducts = clad.getCheckedItems();
final QuickLinksGridViewAdaptor selected_apps = new QuickLinksGridViewAdaptor(HomeActivity.this, mArrayProducts);
gv_shortcut.setAdapter(selected_apps);
```